# jquery: if children with specific class?

Tags: jquery

i wonder how i can determine if a ul has MORE than 2 children and if there are two children with two specific classes inside this ul …

```
if($(this).children().length > 2 && $(this).children('.section-title, .active')) {
    $(this).append('<li class="dots">&hellip;</li>');
}
```

???

Comment: Didn't quite understand the second part of the criteria. Are you just saying you want to also know if the two classes are in the ul.

Comment: I think he wants to see if the two ul have different classes.

Comment: yes! exactly! i want to know if there are MORE than two children (li's) and if there are two li's inside with the mentioned classnames. so if there exactly 3 li's inside of the ul, one must be a li with a class of .section-title and another one must have a classname of .active!

Comment: Could you edit the question to make that more clear? E.g. like spinon's bullet list. Also, you may want to tag this question with 'javascript' also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var $ul = $('ul');
if($ul.find("li").length > 2 && $ul.find('.active, .inactive').length  == 2) {
       alert('yes, it is this way');
}​

<ul>
  <li class="active">Whatever</li>
  <li class="inactive">Whatever</li>
  <li>Whatever</li>
  <li>Whatever</li>
</ul>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RtTSM/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var ulChildren = $("li", this);
if (ulChildren.length > 2 && $('li.section-title', ulChildren).length >= 1 && $('li.active', ulChildren).length >= 1)
```

This will check the following rules:

1. There are more than two li elements under the ul
2. There is at least one li with the class of section-title
3. There is at least one li with the class of active

Comment: the description of my problem is rather difficult for me ;)

if a ul has three li's in it, at least two of them must have the mentioned classnames. so there must be all three criterias fullfilled.

Comment: ok so let me tweak my answer then a little because this isn't exactly correct. The above would be close but it would pass if there were 3 active li members in the ul and no section-title which it sounds like is not what you are looking for. So let me change to make sure there is at least one section-title and one active

Comment: Why not just `var ulChildren = $(this).children('li')` ? Btw, you are missing quotation marks. And it probably should be `ulChildren.length > 2`.

Comment: yeah good catch I am missing the quotation marks. Why use .children when you can just the selector for children. Has the same effect except this is only pulling the li objects that are children. Obviosuly in ul there isn't much chance that there would be any children. But with div you could have all kinds of different elements as children and this way you can limit to the tag you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ul = $('#ul_id');
if ($('.class1, .class2', ul).size()>2)
```

you don't need to test the first condition (has more than 2 children), since it's an "AND" condition, and if your second condition satisfies, the first condition is trivial.

James Lin

guanfenglin@gmail.com