# jquery if children has more than 1 div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

How is it possible to get the number of divs, which are in a li element.

Here is my code but it doesn't work. (Doesn't work mean every img gets the class, also when there is just 1 div inside the li.)

```
if($('.lookbook ul li').find('div').length > 1){
    $('.lookbook ul li img').addClass('lbcursor');
}
```

here is my html structure:

```
<div class="lookbook>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div><img/></div>
            <div></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div><img/></div>
            <div></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div></img></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the third img shouldn't get the class.

i want the number of divs in the li element and if there are more than 1 divs it should add the class .lbcursor to the img.

i did find a similar answer here : [jquery: if children with specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176190/jquery-if-children-with-specific-class) but it doesn't work

ah i just recognized, that the if clause is correct. the problem is to which elements i add the class.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work", is it not finding the divs? or not adding the class? Are you looking for direct descendants?

Comment: i edited my question.
yes i'm looking for direct descendants.

Comment: Put a sample code on jsFiddle. Cant see the HTML structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to loop through, and target that element.

```
$('.lookbook ul li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find('div').length > 1) { //if looking for direct descendants then do .children('div').length
      $this.find('img').addClass('lbcursor');
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyqJ9/)**

You can also write this as:

```
$('.lookbook ul li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
      $this.find('img').addClass(function(){ //using function argument syntax for addClass
          return $this.find('div').length > 1 ? "lbcursor" : "";
      });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Clean and simple using the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and the [:nth-of-type()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selectors.

```
$('.lookbook ul li:has(div:nth-of-type(2)) img').addClass('lbcursor');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/tHGQH/)

- P.S - Like the `:nth-of-type()` selector, this would work only if the `div` elements are the direct children of the same element (as seen in your question).

Comment: @PSL - I've tested it on IE7 and it works. jQuery (1.x.x) knows how to handle old browsers while selecting elements.

Comment: agreed, this answer was the neatest one here  +1

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using each with this context so you can make it specific to each element:

```
$('.lookbook ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('div').length > 1) {
     $('.lookbook ul li img').addClass('lbcursor');
  }
});
```

[EDIT]
as noted

```
$('.lookbook ul li img').addClass('lbcursor');
```

should be

```
$(this).find('img').addClass('lbcursor');
```

Comment: in your code as soon as it finds more than one div in ANY of the elements with the '.lookbook ul li' class it will add the lbcursor class to all of the elements that match ".lookbook ul li img"

Comment: the same and correct answer was already given. thanks anyway.

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl Like zoranc said, those two answers are not the same. This answer will simply not work.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your code is fine, but within the if-block you access all images to add the CSS class.

I think your code should look like this:

```
if($('.lookbook ul li').find('div').length > 1){
   $('.lookbook ul li img').find('div').addClass('lbcursor');
}
```

(refactorings to be done).

Mind the additional call to `find()` within the if block.